# Flask redis queue (RQ) worker update parent process from Vault

Tags: kubernetes, redis, hashicorp-vault, rq

I'm working on the project which building system on k8s and running two separated process on two different pods (provider and server), one pod (provider) take responsible for collecting data, other (server) talking with provider and retrieving data to client. For both pods (provider and server) i used RQ worker https://python-rq.org/docs/workers/ to enqueue a job on provider side, all the configuration keys i stored on Vault https://www.vaultproject.io/docs and for the time i ran a pod (provider) on k8s it could take all right keys on Vault's server but if i modify some configures on Vault later on, the provider pod still read the old configures until i restart the provider pod.

I think that when run RQ worker, it will retrieve all of configures of searches from Vault and store it on parent process so each function is run on a child process (https://python-rq.org/docs/workers/), which in python will use the Vault initialization of parent process again. So how can i update those process on parent process without restart the pod everytime i change the configures on Vault.

Comment: Have you looked at Vault agent sidecar injector pattern? https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/platform/k8s/injector

Comment: I'm not read at all, will get back and raise a comment later ! Thanks